# How to Parse XML Response resulted from Solr search engine

Tags: c#, solr, xml-parsing

I am new to solr, currently i am using google mini for the search now migrating to solr , here is what XML result the solr gives, i want to parse it from  C# . but not able to do it.

```
- <doc>
  <str name="author" /> 
- <arr name="content_type">
  <str>application/pdf</str> 
  </arr>
  <str name="id">\\\\M4968\\C$\Sycamore Networks_v1.pdf</str> 
  <date name="last_modified">2005-06-15T14:32:51Z</date> 
- <arr name="title">
  <str>Microsoft Word - Sycamore Networks</str> 
  </arr>
  </doc>
```

Comment: [Solr.Net](http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/)

Comment: "not able to do it" gives us *no* indication of what you've tried or what went wrong. As L.B says, it would be better to use a dedicated Solr client anyway, but in the future please give us more information. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-list

Answer (score 0):

Use the  XDocument class to parse the xml. But i would suggest you to get the response as JSON or a javabin object

Comment: Ok, but i think solr returns only xml, not sure.